# Adding a variable to the serialized buffer without serializing it with protobuf.net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

So I have a class that I want to serialize except for a certain value "key" which 
would be used to identify what class that is to deserialize it.

Now I understand that , that could be done manually but I made a class that handles serialization/deserialization and I wanted to make it as generic as possible.

Example code

```
[ProtoContract]
public class GeneralPacket 
{
   public uint Identity;
   [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
   public uint Arg1;
   [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true)]
   public uint Arg2;
   [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = true)]
   public uint Arg3;
}
```

where I want Identity to be included in stream but not serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a "discriminator". Protobuf-net doesn't currently have any code to support that, especially on the deserialization side (simply writing the extra value is fairly easy: the hard bit is making use of it when reading). What protobuf-net *does* support is:

- various inheritance scenarios with a common ancestor and keyed sub-types
- manual usage via SerializeWithLengthPrefix allowing to to specify a numeric key when serializing, and provide a type resolver (from key to type) when deserializing

If there is a good use case for stronger discriminator support I'm happy to consider it, but that doesn't exist today. I'd need to see example intended usage and think about the implementation consequences.